# Will having more searchable attributes in ehcache reduce the performance of cache?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I am working on a project in which we are using ehcache. We are using the search API heavily and have about 5-7 search attributes of the values that we are using.

So, I am wondering would having these many search attributes reduce the performance of cache ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Open Source Ehcache, the search functionality uses brute force. This means that search cost is paid as follows:

1. On insertion into the cache, the search subsystem will make sure that attribute values match the expected type configured.
2. On search, you will have to extract again the attribute value from the mapping - limited to the attributes used in the query.

Given this, yes the number of attributes has a direct performance impact on `put` but none on `get`.

Answer (score 1):

[EhCache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.6/apis/search#making-a-cache-searchable) documentation states following

> Search operations perform in O(n) time.....The test shows search performance of an average of
>   representative queries at 4.6 ms for a 10,000 entry cache, and 427 ms
>   for a 1,000,000 entry cache. Accordingly, standalone implementation is
>   suitable for development and testing.
>
> When using standalone Ehcache without BigMemory for production, it is
>   recommended to search only caches that are less than 1 million
>   elements. Performance of different Criteria vary. For example, here
>   are some queries and their execute times on a 200,000 element cache.
>   (Note that these results are all faster than the times given above
>   because they execute a single Criteria).

Two important things mentioned here are - Performance of different Criteria vary and it matters if there is a single Criteria versus multiple Criteria. Although the actual impact on performance can be found only by benchmarking for your use case - the documentation suggests it has some effect. The best way is to benchmark it yourself.